# How can i flatten hbase cells so i can process the resulting JSON using a Spark RDD or Data frame in scala?

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, hbase, apache-spark-sql

a relative newbie to spark, hbase, and scala here.
I have json (stored as byte arrays) in hbase cells in the same column family but across several thousand column qualifiers. Example (simplified):

> Table name: 'Events'
>
> rowkey: rk1
>   column family: cf1
>
> column qualifier: cq1, cell data (in bytes): {"id":1, "event":"standing"}
>
> column qualifier: cq2, cell data (in bytes): {"id":2, "event":"sitting"}

etc.

Using scala, I can read rows by specifying a timerange

```
  val scan = new Scan()
  val start = 1460542400
  val end = 1462801600
  val hbaseContext = new HBaseContext(sc, conf)
  val getRdd = hbaseContext.hbaseRDD(TableName.valueOf("Events"), scan)
```

If I try to load up my hbase rdd (getRdd) into a dataframe (after converting the byte arrays into string etc.), it only reads the first cell in every row (in the example above, I would only get "standing".

> this code only loads up a single cell for every row returned

```
  val resultsString = getRdd.map(s=>Bytes.toString(s._2.value()))
  val resultsDf = sqlContext.read.json(resultsString)
```

In order to get every cell I have to iterate as below.

```
    val jsonRDD = getRdd.map(
    row => {
      val str = new StringBuilder
      str.append("[")
      val it = row._2.listCells().iterator()
      while (it.hasNext) {
        val cell = it.next()
        val cellstring = Bytes.toString(CellUtil.cloneValue(cell))
        str.append(cellstring)
        if (it.hasNext()) {
          str.append(",")
        }
      }
      str.append("]")
      str.toString()
    }
  )
  val hbaseDataSet = sqlContext.read.json(jsonRDD)
```

I need to add the square brackets and the commas so its properly formatted json for the dataframe to read it.

Questions:

1. Is there a more elegant way to construct the json i.e. some parser that takes in the individual json strings and concatenates them together so its properly formed json?
2. Is there a better capability to flatten hbase cells so i dont need to iterate?
3. For the jsonRdd, the closure that is computed should include the str local variable, so the task executing this code on a node should not be missing the "[", "]" or ",". i.e i wont get parser errors once i run this on the cluster instead of local[*]
4. Finally, is it better to just create a pair RDD from the json or use data frames to perform simple things like counts? Is there some way to measure the efficiency and performance of one vs. the other?

thank you